# How to test whether part of the sample follows log-normal distribution?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, lognormal-distribution

I have a sample data that look like the following figure in a Q-Q plot with log-normal distribution. I performed an Shapiro normality test on the logarithm of the data, and reject the null hypothesis that the sample is drawn from log-normal distribution. However, the data points below 10000 seems to follow log-normal distribution closely. How do I test whether the the data points below 10000 follow log-normal distribution?

[image: Q-Q plot with log-normal]

Comment: The relevant plot would be for log of data and normal quantiles. Often with these tests a rejection just means that the sample size is large enough for the hypothesis to be rejected. It doesn't necessarily mean that the distribution is not adequately close to (log)normal for your purposes. The test can't know your purposes.

Comment: Agreed. I have a hypothesis that these data have a log-normal body and power law tail. I can test the power law tail with the R package `poweRlaw`, but I can't test the log-normal body. For a completeness of my paper, I would like such hypothesis to be tested, but yes, even if the log-normal body is rejected, I can still say that it's close enough for my simulation.

Comment: I don't think that is at all easy to test properly. You need an explicitly parameterised probability distribution as  a mixture. Is either distribution truncated? If you are selecting a threshold by eye, then P-values are suspect if not spurious. It sounds a bit like saying that you see a curved bit and a linear bit on a scatter plot, so you'll test the linear bit with a regression, etc.

Comment: The threshold is selected by the `poweRlaw` package when it is determining the $x_{min}$ of the power law tail. The lower end of the data is truncated, because it is a discrete data and can never go below 1.

Comment: Such a discrete _variable_ cannot be lognormal, if only because it has a definite lower limit.

Comment: Sure, but how about testing whether *part* of the distribution following *part* of log-normal?

Comment: "if only" was just flagging one problem. I don't think you have addressed the concerns in my comments. I don't have positive suggestions for you because I can't recognise this problem as a well posed inferential question. That's unwelcome news, but I can't improve on it.